# How to add TinyMCE to a front-end textarea?

Tags: visual-editor

I would like to let the user edit their comments using TinyMCE.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this plugin before: [Tiny MCE for Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymcecomments/). The plugin page says it's only been updated to WP 2.8.4, so not sure if it's working for more recent versions. Try it and see!